# Zend Framework with Kohana PHP 3

Tags: php, zend-framework, kohana

I've put the Zend library folder into classes folder of my app and renamed all files and folders to lowercase ( using Ant Renamer ).

When I call Zend_Feed, instead of loading /classes/zend/feed.php, kohana loads Zend from my servers `share\ZendFramework\library\Zend\` (Zend Server), so I get a `Cannot redeclare class Zend_Uri_Http` error.

ZF version; 1.10
Kohana version: the most recent files available through GitHub

Edit:
https://github.com/kolanos/kohana-zend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kohana autoloader expects lowercase filenames. You can register both Zend and Kohana autoloaders and it should work fine.

In bootstrap you have:

```
/**
 * Enable the Kohana auto-loader.
 *
 * @see  http://docs.kohanaphp.com/features/autoloading
 * @see  http://php.net/spl_autoload_register
 */
spl_autoload_register(array('Kohana', 'auto_load'));
```

Zend autoloader should go before or after that (I don't know if that makes a difference). Found a post how to do it:
http://www.beyondcoding.com/2009/10/29/using-zend-framework-1-8-with-kohana/

Comment: And where exactly do I register that? I'm new to Kohana and don't really know where and how I'm supposed to define autoload for, lets say, every class name with Zend_ prefix. Bootstrap ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

its very important that your class name matches the file path in ko3. e.g. your feed class is inside `/classes/zend/feed.php` so it must be named `class Zend_Feed {` if you don't like this you can create this file `/classes/feed.php` and do this `class Feed extends Zend_Feed { }`

Comment: It already is that way, zend's got a very similar autoload as kohana

Answer (score 0):

As Pomyk says, try to use both autoloaders: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Reneming classes is bad practice, because it's very difficult to update and feauture support